# Install directly in the pendrive

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and i would like to know if it's possible to install a app. directly in the pendrive??

Like for example if we want to install vlc we type in the terinal
sudo apt-get install vlc
but what should be written if we want that to be installed in the pendrive (/media/PENDRIVE)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that.

Only possibility for permanent software installation on USB stick is formatting to Ext4 and full Ubuntu installation to it (like it's a hard drive partition).